# Finding the effect of a covariate averaged over all other covariates and interactions in R

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, interaction, emmeans

I am running a linear mixed model in R using data with repeated measures for a project and as part of my analysis I need to determine what the effect of time is (how much the outcome changes from one study visit to the next). This is easy to get from looking at model summaries, but my model is fairly complex and features multiple terms that are interacted with the visit number, therefore the interpretation of this covariate is nuanced. For example, in my analysis I run two different models, each with a different exposure I am curious about, and the effect of time on the outcome is very different in the two models! In talking with some colleagues, they suggested using the emmeans package to get the effect of time averaged over all other covariates and interactions. But I'm having trouble with this. Here is some example data and a model that resemble my own (though much simpler):

```
library(lme4)
library(emmeans)

example <-  data.frame("subject" = c(rep(1,5), rep(2,5), rep(3, 5)),"outcome" = c(15,13,10,10,9,12,12,11,9,9,18,14,12,11,10), "visit" = c(rep(sequence(5), 3)), "sex"= c(rep("male", 10), rep("female", 5)), current_age = c(rep("20-24", 3), rep("25-29", 2), rep("30-34", 4), rep("35-39", 1), rep("20-24", 1), rep("25-29", 4)), "exposure" = c(10, 9, 9, 8, 6, 12, 12, 12, 11, 10, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9))

example_mod <- lmer(outcome ~ (visit | subject) + visit + sex + visit:current_age + visit:exposure, data = example)
```

Note: A feature of the complex models I am using is that there are interactions with "visit" that do not have the main effect terms for the other covariate. Also, I know the model produces an error about a singular fit, I am ignoring this for the sake of the example. Here is the summary of fixed effects:

```
Fixed effects:
                       Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)            20.08153    2.60105   7.721
visit                  -0.59361    0.87432  -0.679
sexmale                -4.39004    2.99455  -1.466
visit:current_age25-29  0.11279    0.35448   0.318
visit:current_age30-34  1.42966    0.58610   2.439
visit:current_age35-39  1.34885    0.51105   2.639
visit:exposure         -0.18092    0.08711  -2.077
```

So the effect of visit is estimated to be -0.59361, but this is for females in the age group 20-24 with 0 exposure. I need to find the effect of visit averaged across sex, current age, and exposure.

I have played around a little with the emmeans package with the following code/output:

```
emmeans(example_mod, "visit")


 visit emmean   SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
     3   12.7 2.28 0.5     -359      385

Results are averaged over the levels of: sex, current_age 
Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

So this tells me the average visit value (3) and what the mean outcome is at visit 3 (12.7), but how do I specifically extract the effect of visit and not just get the marginal mean? Is that possible with emmeans or is there another approach I should be using altogether?

Comment: I think you might be looking for `emtrends` ?

Comment: E.g. `emtrends(example_mod, ~1, var = 'visit')` to get the slope of `visit` averaged over sex and age.

Comment: @Axeman, please post as answer ...

Answer (score 0):

`emmeans` calculates, as the name suggests, means of groups. If you are interested in a slope parameter, the `emtrends` function is more suitable. These are still marginal, i.e. averaged over the other parameters in the model.

In your case, I think what you want is:

```
emtrends(example_mod, specs = ~1, var = 'visit')
```

The `~1` as the `specs` argument just means that you want the overall average slope. This gives:

> ```
>  1       visit.trend   SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
>  overall       -1.73 0.45 1.51    -4.42    0.959
>
> Results are averaged over the levels of: sex, current_age 
> Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
> Confidence level used: 0.95
> ```

You can see what the slopes are per group, which are being averaged over, by running

```
summary(emtrends(example_mod, var = 'visit'))
```

> ```
>  visit sex    current_age exposure visit.trend    SE   df
>      3 female 20-24           10.3       -2.45 0.705 5.84
>      3 male   20-24           10.3       -2.45 0.705 5.84
>      3 female 25-29           10.3       -2.34 0.579 1.72
>      3 male   25-29           10.3       -2.34 0.579 1.72
>      3 female 30-34           10.3       -1.02 0.782 1.40
>      3 male   30-34           10.3       -1.02 0.782 1.40
>      3 female 35-39           10.3       -1.10 0.806 0.38
>      3 male   35-39           10.3       -1.10 0.806 0.38
> ```

So here we see that each of slopes is calculated at the average `exposure` (10.3), and then the slopes are averaged across age and sex (which is what is reported above). Although in this case, since `visit:sex` isn't actually in the model, the slopes are identical for each sex and the slopes are really just averaged over ages.

Comment: This is great, thank you so much for the detailed response!!